# how to pass params from launch file to cpp file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all

i have some params which i defined in my launch file as below :

```
<node name="tfs" pkg="ctt_tools" type="tfs" respawn="true" />
<param name = "point_x_1" value = "23" />
<param name = "point_x_2" value = "26" />
<param name = "point_y_1" value = "-4.70" />
<param name = "point_y_2" value = "4.50" />
</node>
```

and i want to use these params in my cpp file in the code as below :

```
        if(m.point.x > 23 && m.point.x < 26 && m.point.y > -4.70 && m.point.y < 4.50 )
        { 
            for (int i=0; i<palletdrop.size();i++)
            {
                if(palletdrop[i].isInside(m.point.x,m.point.y))
                {
                    palletdrop[i].setOccupied();
                    //std::cout<<"Another on area "<<i<<std::endl;
                }
            }
        
        }
```

in place of values 23 , 26 etc i want o use params i defined in launch file...
how can i do that ???

any suggestions?

thanks all ..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258638/how-to-pass-params-from-launch-file-to-cpp-file/) by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example of how to do that.

```
<node name="tfs" pkg="ctt_tools" type="tfs" respawn="true"/> 
    <param name="param_1" value="23.0" />
</node>
```

and

```
double param_1;
node_handle.getParam("/tfs/param_1", param_1);      
if(m.point.x > param_1 && m.point.x < 26 && m.point.y > -4.70 && m.point.y < 4.50 )
{ 
   ...
}
```

You could also refer to [Parameters in launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects#roslaunch.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-Roslaunch_tips_for_larger_projects.Parameters.2C_namespaces.2C_and_yaml_files) and [Use parameters in roscpp](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters#Setting_Parameters) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) with karma: 271 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2017-04-06**:
thanks a lot,, it worked absolutely fine ..